# Maximum length between two points

Tags: calculus, functions

There is given:

$$f(x) = x^2$$
$$g(x) = x$$

A parallel line to the $x$-axis is put so there is two cut points between the line and the two functions.

> Find the biggest length of the line that connects the two functions.

I tried the length between $(x, x)$  and $(x, x^2)$ but didn't work.

**EDIT:** To explain it better, which *orange* line is bigger?
[image]

Comment: Two cut points between the line and the two functions. Could you please explain that for me?

Comment: A line parallel to $x$-axis having 2 cut points?? Not possible. It can be $1$ or $3$ but not $2$.

Comment: So you want the maximum horizontal distance between $x^2,x$... Over what interval?

Comment: @abiessu : the way the OP formulated the problem, I'm not even sure the line must be horizontal

Comment: As well, it is confusing that the problem is referenced as "maximum length between two *points*"

Comment: Sorry for my bad explaining (and translation)! I edited a bit the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the point on the line $y=x$ as some $(a,a)$. The point on the curve $y=x^2$ will be $(\sqrt a,a)$ since their $y$ coordinate must be the same.

Now we must maximise the function $\sqrt a -a$

(Since that is the length of the line you have drawn as orange.)

$${1\over {2\sqrt a}}-1=0$$

$\Rightarrow$ $$a=1/4$$

Substituting that in $\sqrt a -a$

The length is also $1/4$

Another solution is to see that the distance between the two curves between $0$ and $1$ is maximum when the slope of the curve $y=x^2$ is equal to the slope of $y=x$

Comment: Why $(\sqrt{a}, a)$?

Comment: @PichiWuana: A line parallel to the $x$-axis means that the $y$ coordinate is the same for all points on that line. I already assumed the $y$ coordinate to be $a$ and since it lies on the curve $y=x^2$ the point is $(\sqrt a,a)$

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the "parallel line to the $x-$ axis" is of the form $x = a$, in which case the result of the length of this line is fixed. Is this what you mean? If $a < 1$ then the length of the line is $a - \sqrt{a}$, and has a maximum when $a = 1/4$. If $a > 1$ the length of the line is $\sqrt{a} - a$ and there is no maximum.

Comment: I edited the question if there was a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to think about it in terms of switching axes. If $y = f(x) = x^2$ and $y_1 = g(x) = x_1$ then $$x = \sqrt{y}$$ and $$ x_1 = y_1$$ Your job is to find the maximum value of $x - x_1$. This is easily done by differentiating with respect to $y$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Differentiate

$$(\sqrt y -y) $$

with respect to $y$,equate to zero,...